# Lower bound on the number of distinct polynomials of degree less than $t$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, primality-test

[image: Primes in P number of distinct polynomials]

In the Primes in P paper there is a section which states that there are at least $t+l \choose t-1$ distinct polynomials of degree $<t$ in a certain group. I think this can be deduced only from the line above that states that the $X+a$ are unique and non zero.
My idea: There are at least $l+1 \choose i$ unique polynomials of degree $i$ (just choose $i$ of the $l+1$ different $X+a$) and therefore there must be at least $\sum_{i=1}^{t-1} {l+1 \choose i}$ many polynomials of degree $<t$. My hope was that $\sum_{i=1}^{t-1} {l+1 \choose i} = {t+l \choose t-1}$ but I don't know if this is even true? I tried using Pascal's identity, which at least for me did not work.

Any suggestions on the last equality or on the original statement are highly appreciated.

I am highly confident that this question is self contained and could also be asked in the following way: Given l+1 distinct polynomials of degree one show that there are at least $ t+l \choose t-1$ polynomials of degree $<t$.

Nevertheless I included the link to the "PRIMES is in P" paper https://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/manindra/algebra/primality_v6.pdf as there is still a possibility that I am mistaken.

Comment: I'm sure the "Primes in P" paper is so well-known that this alone is a sufficient reference for the rest of the world, but alas, I am unaware of it. Thus I have no place to go to look up all the context you didn't bother to include, though your question is dependent on it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment I have edited my post and added the two paragraphs to the end of my original question.

Comment: Your hope fails. For example, $\ell = 5, t = 3$ yields $$\sum_{i=1}^{t-1} {\ell+1 \choose i} = {6 \choose 1}+{6 \choose 2} = 21\\{t+\ell \choose t-1} = {8 \choose 2} = 28$$ Perhaps they are including polynomials that are not square-free?

Comment: Thank you for your answer I will look into that